# touch handling inside another view

Tags: ios, delegates, event-handling, touch, uiwebviewdelegate

I assume my problem is an easy one but currently I have some difficulties.
I want to use a ViewOne as touch-input view - for example an UIImageView
and another view that will handle and use all those touch events. Could be an UIWebView
View1 = touchInputView
View2 = TouchHandlingView

Can't I just say something like View1.touchDelegate = View2

Comment: add your code for reference?

Comment: Get your ViewOne to implement a delegate and send the events to others views.

Comment: Well that's basically what I am trying. I collect all UIResponder touch events - like - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event and forward this to my second view. In this case a UIWebview. But nothing happens. The second screen is on the second window - on appleTV maybe there is the problem?!

Comment: I would be VERY interested in the solution to this - we are having the same need and have not yet found a solid or clear solution.